# Some mysql concurrent caused by php or js

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, concurrency

I come to a concurrent problem.
In mysql the data like this:

```
id  tel           date_time 
1   13313131333   2014-01-01 11:00:01
2   13313131333   2014-01-01 11:00:01
3   13313131333   2014-01-01 11:00:01
```

which I want a unique tel.
Is the php or js code cause the problem?

javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
dataType : 'jsonp',
data: {
  'tel':tel,
},
jsonp : 'callback',
url: "http://my.com/adduserinfo",
success: function(data){}
})
```

php code:

```
$Dreamcity = new Dreamcity;
$tel = $_GET['tel'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$result = $Dreamcity->getPeopleInfoByTel($tel);
if(!empty($result)){
   $data = array('msg'=>'tel exists','result'=>1);
}else{
   $result = $Dreamcity->insertPeople($tel,$date);
}

$result=json_encode($data);       

$callback=$_GET['callback'];    

echo $callback."($result)";
```

Comment: Usually you don't use the get method for changing (inserting, deleting) data. It may be cached, it may be prefetched, ...

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Comment: @VMai . I'll keep in mind :) thanks

Comment: If you want a field to be unique in the db, set it as `unique` in the db rather than relying on php or js for this.